# How to show list of all users name in a related list who have visited a case?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I want to display the names of all users in a related list on case detail page  who have visited that specific case record?
For e.g : Case number 123 has been viewd by user "A" and user "B" so the related list on Case number 123 will display the names A and B

Answer (score 0):

I dont think its possible unless you make them commit some sort of change to the record. Viewing is certainly not tracked by SF per se.